# Internal laptop display is disconnected (LVDS-0 disconnected)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, laptop, 16.04

I did a clean install of ubuntu gnome 16.04 on my lenovo w520 (without formatting the home partition; before I had ubuntu gnome 15.10).
My laptop comes (sadly - since I have always had troubles with it) with an nvidia quadro 2000M (with optimus support) installed on it. Under 15.10 all worked fine. Now, when I install the nvidia proprietary driver (nvidia-361) the laptop screen isn't detected. If I plug in the external monitor, this is working fine, but the laptop screen never works.
Does someone have an idea? I already tried to reconfigure xorg, I deleted the ~/.config/monitors.xml file. What else could it be? Could it be that some configuration is remained from the older installation in the home directory?

Here are some useful informations:

```
david@david-ubuntu:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

xorg.conf:

```
david@david-ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/X11/
cat: /etc/X11/: Is a directory
david@david-ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf 
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that is a problem with the 361 driver. Installing older ones does not solve the problem, but installing the 364 via ppa solved the problem.

If you need info on how to add the ppa you can [follow this link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/08/ubuntu-nvidia-graphics-drivers-ppa-is-ready-for-action).

Comment: For some reason, the 364 driver didn't work on my Thinkpad P50 machine with an nVidia M1000M GPU. Any insight?

Comment: No, I do not really have insights. I just read on the forum of the italian ubuntu community that some users solved the problem by deactivating the secure boot option in their BIOS, some others by using lxde (which is not really a solution)... I'm sorry I can't help you in a better way

Comment: I have w530 with three monitors - I could either use nouveau driver and have the internal screen detected but it would not drive the three monitors as they are too large for it. The other option for me is to turn Discrete graphics on in BIOS - then the internal screen works. But I think this is a different problem with the same symptoms.